# Referring to a column through a character variable in data.table R

Tags: r, data.table, subset

I am using data.table and I want to filter a data.table within a function where I am passing the name of the column as a character vector.

For a simple reproducible example let's take the mtcars dataset of base R.

I can write using data.table syntax:

```
mtcars[am == 1, .N ]
```

But what if the name of the variable of interest -- i.e. am -- is stored as a character vector, i.e. "am"?

Your advice will be appreciated.

Comment: `DT = data.table(mtcars); vname = "am"; DT[.(1), on=vname, .N]` is what I'd do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option is to use `get` (*?get* search object by name):

```
mtcars[get('am') == 1, .N]
# [1] 13
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to specify it in the `.SDcols`

```
mtcars[, sum(.SD==1) ,.SDcols = 'am']
#[1] 13
```

We can also include multiple variables

```
mtcars[, sum(Reduce(`&`, lapply(.SD, `==`, 1))), .SDcols = c('am', 'carb')]
#[1] 4
```